# How to modify WebKit context menu?

Tags: python-3.x, webkit, gtk3

I am developping a small application. I would like to modify the default context menu of the WebKit webview. Specifically I would like to

- block/hide context menu
- add item to context menu
- remove item from context menu
- remove all items from context menu

I am looking for solutions for

- Python 2 and WebKit
- Python 3 and WebKit2

#### Python 2 and WebKit

What works:

- block/hide context menu
- add item to context menu

What does not work:

- remove item from context menu
- remove all items from context menu

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="test")

        self.wv = WebKit.WebView()
        self.add(self.wv)

        # add item
        def append_item(webview, context_menu, hit_result_event, event):
            option = Gtk.ImageMenuItem('Extra')
            context_menu.append(option)
            option.show()

        # select case, change this to "1", "2" etc.
        x = 0

        # block/hide context menu
        if x == 1:
            settings = self.wv.get_settings()
            settings.set_property('enable-default-context-menu', False)
        # add item
        elif x == 2:
            self.wv.connect('context-menu', append_item)
        # remove item
        # ???
        # remove all items
        # ???

win = MyWindow()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

#### Python 3 and WebKit2

What works:

- block/hide context menu
- add item to context menu
- remove all items from context menu

What does not work:

- remove item from context menu
- icons in context menu (no icons are displayed)

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, WebKit2

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="test")

        self.wv = WebKit2.WebView()
        self.add(self.wv)

        # block/hide context menu
        def context_menu_block(self, event, case):
            # right-click
            if case == "button":
                if event.button == 3:
                    return True
            # keyboard
            elif case == "key":
                state = event.state
                shift = (state & Gdk.ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK)
                # menu key
                if event.keyval == 65383:
                    return True
                # shift & F10
                elif shift and event.keyval == 65479:
                    return True

        # add item
        def append_item(webview, context_menu, hit_result_event, event):
            action = Gtk.Action("FileNewStandard", "_New", "Create a new file", Gtk.STOCK_NEW)
            option = WebKit2.ContextMenuItem().new(action)
            context_menu.append(option)

        # remove all items
        def remove_all_items(webview, context_menu, hit_result_event, event):
            context_menu.remove_all()

        # select case, change this to "1", "2" etc.
        x = 0

        # block/hide context menu
        if x == 1:
            self.wv.connect('button-press-event', context_menu_block, "button")
            self.wv.connect('key-press-event', context_menu_block, "key")
        # add item
        elif x == 2:
            self.wv.connect('context-menu', append_item)
        # remove item
        # ???
        # remove all items
        elif x == 3:
            self.wv.connect('context-menu', remove_all_items)

win = MyWindow()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/WebKit2-4.0/classes/WebView.html#WebKit2.WebView.signals.context_menu), you can turn off the context menu by connecting to `"context-menu"` signal and returning True to hide the context menu.

Here is your code updated to what you are looking for, I believe:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, WebKit2

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="test")

        self.wv = WebKit2.WebView()
        self.add(self.wv)
        self.wv.connect('context-menu', self.append_item)

        # add item
    def append_item(self, webview, context_menu, hit_result_event, event):
        context_menu.remove_all()
        action = Gtk.Action("FileNewStandard", "_New", "Create a new file", Gtk.STOCK_NEW)
        option = WebKit2.ContextMenuItem().new(action)
        context_menu.append(option)

win = MyWindow()
win.show_all()
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Ok, so I managed to block the context menu. However, that way the custom context menu that I wanted to be displayed instead, is blocked as well. - The documentation mentions the possibility to modify the default context menu by adding or removing items. How does that work? Sorry, I can't find any examples. `wv.ContextMenu` ... does not work.

Comment: I suggest you fully read the documentation I linked. There is a `remove_all` that could be used to remove all the widgets and then you can add your own. A lot of different scenarios are explained in the docs.

Comment: When I try `wv.ContextMenu.remove_all()` I get `AttributeError: 'WebView' object has no attribute 'ContextMenu'`.

Comment: Obviously you are calling it on the wrong object (WebView). You need to access the context menu somehow.

Comment: Obviously. But how can the context menu be accessed? (I did read the documentation.)

Comment: Update your question with the code you currently have. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve